# How to install memcached 1.4.5 on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am trying to set up the environment to work with a Ruby application that requires a memcached server installation to work with the Dalli client. Dalli requires memcached 1.4+.

I am installing this on Windows 7.

When installing memcached 1.4.5 I get the message ‘Failed to ignore SIGHUP: Result too large.’
Even with this message the memcached was installed, but when I try to start the service I get the message:

```
Windows could not start the memcached service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request 
in a timely fashion.
```

I was able to successfully install and start the service for memcached 1.2.6, but the Dalli client fails to connect to the server (I am assuming this is because the memcached is not v1.4+).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get memcached 1.4.5 installed on Windows 7?

Comment: You are suppose to just install it and configure it, then it should work there are no special instructions beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue exactly. [As far as I understand](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/issues/detail?id=149), the "install/run as a service" (-d) parameter is no longer available:

> The use of -d for installing as a service was never really sufficient
>   for most installs, as you really need a way to manage the arguments to
>   memcached.
>
> The -d should not generate that error message, but it will, starting
>   with 1.4.5, no longer support installing itself as a windows service.

I also tried to force the install via sc:

```
sc create memcached binPath= C:\memcached\memcached.exe start= auto
```

Still the same 1053 error (other users report the same).

I'm still looking for a solution. Meanwhile, running the memcached.exe via Task Scheduler is a working stopgap.

Answer (score 0):

Which memceched 1.4.5 package are you using? If you are using the Northscale package, note that the command line is different vs. the 1.2.6 build from Jellycan. The "-d" option doesn't seem to work on that later version.

And how did you install 1.4.5 as a service? This [tutorial shows what we had to do to get 1.4.5 to run as a service](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunMemcachedAsAService.html) with our commercial application.